# OnFormClosing and e.CloseReason

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has two buttons on it "Cancel" and "OK". In the handler for the "Cancel" button I do whatever roll back I need to do and then call `this.Close()`. In the handler for the "OK" button I do whatever committing I need to do and then call `this.Close()`.

So I realise now that a user might also click the "X" icon in the top right of the form to close the form. I should be treating this the same as I do with the "Cancel" button, but I have no way to override the "X" button. The best I can do is to add a handler for the `OnFormClosing` event.

I'm still confused though and uncertain what the best way to deal with this issue is. There are many other reasons that the form can close as well (like ALT-F4 or Windows shutting down) I'd like to treat all of these the same as a "Cancel" button.

But, whether I close the form by clicking "X", "Close" (which ultimately calls `this.Close()`) or "OK" (which also ultimately calls `this.Close()`), the value for `e.CloseReason` is the same (`UserClosing`) and the value for `sender` is also the same so I can't distinguish.

What is the best way to implement roll back if the form closes for any reason other than the "OK" button being clicked?

Comment: Please read about DialogResult property. If you want create custom reason info just create additional property in your form.

Comment: This is not a Dialog, it's an ordinary form that is displayed by using Form.Show(). DialogResult is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a boolean inside your OK button handler, and check that boolean inside your OnFormClosing() override, like so:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);

        if (!this.isClosingViaOkButton)
        {
            // ...do your rollback here.

            MessageBox.Show("Rolling back");
        }
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...do your committing here.

        this.isClosingViaOkButton = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    private bool isClosingViaOkButton;
}
```

As an alternative, instead of committing in the OK button handler and rolling back in the OnFormClosing(), you could do both in the OnFormClosing(), like this:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (this.isClosingViaOkButton)
    {
        // ...do your committing.
    }
    else
    {
        // ...do your rollback.
    }
}
```

I prefer this approach myself.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need `CloseReason`, do you?

```
private bool _closing;
private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
{
    e.Cancel = !_closing; // prevent form from being closed
}

// inside OK and Cancel button handler
...
_closing = true;
Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

On some forms I get around the problem by hiding the X button using Win32 functions - don't know if it is appropriate for your situation, but the code is below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Win32 function to get window information
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hWnd">Window handle</param>
/// <param name="nIndex">Information to get</param>
/// <returns>Required Window Information</returns>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
/// <summary>
/// Code to get/set Style for window
/// </summary>
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
/// <summary>
/// System menu bit
/// </summary>
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;

/// <summary>
/// Hide close button on window
/// </summary>
/// <param name="w">Window to set</param>
/// <remarks>Actually removes all of system menu from window title bar</remarks>
public static void HideCloseButton(Window w)
{
  var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(w).Handle;
  NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
}
/// <summary>
/// Show close button on window
/// </summary>
/// <param name="w">Window to set</param>
/// <remarks>Actually shows all of system menu from window title bar</remarks>
public static void ShowCloseButton(Window w)
{
  var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(w).Handle;
  NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) | WS_SYSMENU);
}
```

Comment: I call it in the window loaded event :     private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      LibW2.HideCloseButton(this);
    }

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the "x" button to be invisible. That would break with consistency in my application. And it seems like circumventing the problem, rather than addressing the problem.